# boost lambda question

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, stl-algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::lambda;



class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int i, const string &s) : m_i(i) , m_s(s) {}
    int get_i() const { return m_i; }
    const string &get_s() const { return m_s; }
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const Foo &f) {
        os << f.get_i() << " " << f.get_s().c_str() << endl;
        return os;
    }
private:
    int m_i;
    string m_s;
};

typedef set<Foo> fooset;
typedef set<int> intset;


int main()
{
    fooset fs;
    intset is;

    fs.insert(Foo(1, "one"));
    fs.insert(Foo(2, "two"));
    fs.insert(Foo(3, "three"));
    fs.insert(Foo(4, "four"));

    transform(fs.begin(), fs.end(), inserter(is, is.begin()), boost::bind(&Foo::get_i, _1));

    std::for_each(fs.begin(), fs.end(), cout << _1 << endl);
    std::for_each(is.begin(), is.end(), cout << _1 << endl);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my code example.  I want to for_each a set of Foo and produce a set of a type of a member of Foo, in this case an int.  I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, but I am definitely doing something wrong.

TIA for your help!

edit: THANKS Guys!  Working code is below...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::lambda;


class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int i, const string &s) : m_i(i) , m_s(s) {}
    int get_i() const { return m_i; }
    const string &get_s() const { return m_s; }
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const Foo &f) {
        os << f.get_i() << " " << f.get_s().c_str() << '\n';
        return os;
    }

private:
    int m_i;
    string m_s;
};

bool operator < (const Foo &lf, const Foo &rf) {
    return (lf.get_i() < rf.get_i()); 
}

typedef set<Foo> fooset;
typedef set<int> intset;


int main()
{
    fooset fs;
    intset is;

    fs.insert(Foo(1, "one"));
    fs.insert(Foo(2, "two"));
    fs.insert(Foo(3, "three"));
    fs.insert(Foo(4, "four"));

    transform(fs.begin(), fs.end(), inserter(is, is.begin()), boost::lambda::bind(&Foo::get_i, boost::lambda::_1));

    std::for_each(fs.begin(), fs.end(), cout << boost::lambda::_1 << '\n');
    std::for_each(is.begin(), is.end(), cout << boost::lambda::_1 << '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  Is that the problem you want help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program runs and produces the expected output after the following changes:

1. implement `Foo::operator<(const Foo&) const` (otherwise `set<Foo>` will not compile)
2. put `typedef set<Foo> fooset;` after `class Foo`
3. disambiguate _1 between the boost.bind and boost.lambda placeholders
4. use '\n' instead of endl, as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly don't mix up boost::bind and boost::lambda::bind, they're different things.

Change the call to boost::bind in the foreach loop to this (Remove the boost:: prefix):

```
bind (&Foo::get_i, _1)
```

Then change the `endl`s at the bottom to `'\n'`.